# What are semantically correct alternatives to \text in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, semantics

I have used `\text{something}` several times in math mode. The result is rendered like I want it to be rendered, but I think this might not the best way to do it in LaTeX.

## What I currently do

### Hopefully correct usage of \text

- `$\fT_\text{triv} = \Set{\emptyset, X}$`: Denote the [trivial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology).

A longer one:

```
\begin{align*}
    U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \text{ offen} \Leftrightarrow 
       &\text{ für jedes } x \in U \text{ gibt es } r > 0,\\
       &\text{ sodass } \fB_r(x) = \Set{y \in \mdr^n | d(x,y) < r} \subseteq U
\end{align*}
```

### Probably incorrect

- `$g \circ f = \text{id}_X$`: Donote the identity function.
- `$\text{Isom}(X)$`: [Isometry group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_group)
- `$\text{grad}(F)(x) \neq 0$`: Degree of a function
- `$\text{conv}(v_0, \dots, v_k)`: Convex hull of some points

## Alternatives to \text

I've searched for alternatives and found the following:

- `\[ \text{Let } x = \text{ number of cats} \]`: Provided by the `amsmath` package.
- `\[ \mbox{Let } x = \mbox{ number of cats} \]`
- `\[ \textrm{Let } x = \textrm{ number of cats} \]`
- `\operatorname{sgn}` and `\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}`: Provided by `amsmath`. I think I should use this for my currently incorrect usages. But I'm not sure if this is semantically correct.
- `$\mathrm{Gal}(f)$`

`\newcommand{\x}[1]{\text{#1}}` might also be interesting. This would at least give me a command for groups / the identity. At the end, it will also be text, but it lets me switch easier to better variants.

## Questions

- Are the two examples which I labeled as correct actually correct? Are there better alternatives?
- How do the "Alternatives to \text" differ? Did I miss some good ones?
- What should I use for my "Probably incorrect" ones?

## Related questions

I've read the following questions and answers (which did only partially help):

- [What is the “correct” way of embedding text into math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3415/5645)
- [Text mode commands/symbols in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103429/5645)
- [Avoiding italicization in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125718/5645)

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid you hit no correct choice. `;-)`

- `$\fT_\text{triv} = \Set{\emptyset, X}$`: incorrect. Define

  ```
  \newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % textual subscript
  ```

  and use `$\fT_{\ts{triv}}`. You can later change your mind about the typesetting of `\ts`. With `\text` you're not guaranteed to get upright shape, for example in the statement of a theorem.
- `$g \circ f = \text{id}_X$`: incorrect. Define

  ```
  \newcommand{\id}{\textnormal{id}}
  ```

  (or with `\textit`, which I'd prefer).
- `$\text{Isom}(X)$`: incorrect. It's an operator, so `$\operatorname{Isom}(X)$`. Defining a command with `\DeclareMathOperator` is of course a good choice. The same considerations hold for “grad”, “cov”, ”sgn” and ”Gal”.
- `\[ \text{Let } x = \text{ number of cats} \]`: incorrect. “Let” should not go in the displayed equation. So

  ```
  Let
  \[
  x=\text{number of cats}
  \]
  ```

  with no space before “number”.

The longer one should be

```
\begin{align*}
U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \text{ offen} \Leftrightarrow 
  &\text{für jedes $x \in U$ gibt es $r > 0$,}\\
  &\text{sodass $\fB_r(x) = \Set{y \in \mdr^n | d(x,y) < r} \subseteq U$}
\end{align*}
```

so you don't have to think where spaces are necessary.

I wouldn't use a macro `\Set` with delimited argument, preferring

```
\newcommand{\Set}[2]{\{\,#1\mid #2\,\}}
```

and `\Set{y \in \mdr^n}{d(x,y) < r}`. This is more consistent with LaTeX syntax. If your `\Set` macro has just one normal argument, then use `\mid` and not `|`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed my document according to your recommendations. Can you please also tell me what's the difference between `textrm` and `mathrm`? When should `mbox` be used? By the way, I use `\Set` from the `braket` package.

Comment: Or better, use this answer to define `\Set`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150516/3929, I'm no longer a fan of the two argument version, preferring one that makes more sense when read

Comment: @moose `\mathrm` uses a math alphabet, which for letters happens to be the same as the main text font; `\textrm` just does the same it does in normal text.

Answer (score 3):

`\text` is a relatively complex and tricky operation and should only really be used for embedding a textual phrase using the font setup of the outer text flow. Your examples all seem to be mathematical identifiers so I would use `\mathrm` if you want a normal (`\mathord`) symbold (`\mathrm{Id}`) or `\DeclareMathOperator` (which is just a nicer declarative way of getting `\mathop{\mathrm{grad}}` when you want a log-like operator spacing.

But if your real example is "number of cats" rather than `Isom` then probably I'd use `\text`.